# New page on Google Sites not showing on tabs

Tags: google-classic-sites

I developed a new page about history on Google Sites and I am able to see that page (`History`) through the sitemap. However, I am not able to see that similar page on main tabs which are always present at right-hand side on the website to browse across the website.

I am new to Google Sites so I am not sure where exactly am I going wrong in making a new page and showing it on main tabs. The way I developed the new page  was to click on `New page (c)` while being on `Home`, and once it directed me to name the new page then choosing the option as shown below:

[image: new page dialog]

Can someone help me to display the name of the new page on the tabs shown in figure above?

Comment: I had the same issue. To resolve it I went to: https://support.google.com/sites/answer/187377?hl=en It WORKED!

Answer (score 2):

In order to make a tab show up in the navigation menu of your Sites pages, you will need to add it manually. Creating a new page doesn't add it to the navigation automatically.

Go to:
*More* > *Edit Site Layout* > **Click the navigation menu** > *Add Page*

You can then select the page you want and it should show up in your navigation menu.